# Big integer java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger not invertible

Tags: java

Писал свой rsa. В нем необходимо возведение в степень по модулю. При некоторых значениях выбрасывает exception java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger not invertible. Что это и как с этим бороться ? 
Пример кода выбрасывающего исключение

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long g = -319;
        long b = -2725;
        long p =8497;
        byte s = powwowbyte(g,b,p);
    }

    public static byte powwowbyte(long g,long b_d, long p)
    {
        try {
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(g));
            BigInteger b = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b_d));
            BigInteger c = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(p));
            if (Integer.parseInt(a.toString()) == 0)
                return 0;
            a = a.modPow(b, c);   //тут ошибка 
            if (Integer.parseInt(a.toString()) > 127) {
                return -128;
            }
            byte result = Byte.parseByte(a.toString());
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
        System.exit(0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vartlok пример значения прям в коде выше, он прям выбросит эксепшн. Начинающий программист и с логами пока не сталкивался((

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)) к методу `modPow` написано:

> Throws:
>
> ArithmeticException - if m ≤ 0 or the exponent is negative and this
>   BigInteger is not relatively prime to m.

Что значит, что исключение выбросится, если `m` неположительно или если экспонента отрицательна и данное число не является взаимно простым с модулем.

Ваше число равно -319, модуль равен 8497. Простая проверка `a.gcd(с)` дает ответ 29, т.е. вы нарушаете контракт метода. И насколько я помню основы криптографии, числа там таки должны быть взаимно простыми :).